# The return value is displayed as 0.0. Why is it so?

Tags: java

```
public   class    employee {

 String empname; 
    int  empcode    ; 
   double basicpay;

    employee()
    {
        empname     =  "";
        empcode     =  0;
        basicpay     =  0.0;
    }
    employee(String n , int p , double q)
    {
        n = empname;
        p = empcode;
        q = basicpay;
    }
    double salarycal()
    {
        double salary,hra,da,allowance,totalsalary;allowance = 0;totalsalary = 0;
        hra = 0.3*basicpay;
        da = 0.4*basicpay;
        salary = basicpay + hra + da;
        if(empcode<=15 && salary<=15000)
        {
            allowance = 0.2*salary;
            if (allowance> 2500)

            allowance  =  allowance - (allowance-2500);
        }
        else 
        {
            allowance = 1000;
         }
        totalsalary =salary + allowance;

        return totalsalary;//the problem is that the total salary is not returned.
    }
}
```

Please tell what correction has to be made to the program.

Comment: The fact it is urgent or to solve ASAP is completely unrelated to the main problem. If you need it fast, then go to a site where you **pay** for solutions. Here you receive free help.

Comment: Have you even debugged your application to see what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe one of your constructors is doing assignments backwards. It should probably look like:

```
employee(String n , int p , double q)
{
    empname = n;
    empcode = p;
    basicpay = q;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post this. +1 for beating me to it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Default Constructor** 
in default constructor you are initializing to zero, `basicpay =  0.0`and you are multiplying everything by it so answer is zero.

**Parametrized constructor**  In parametrized constructor you are assigning value wrongly

```
 employee(String n , int p , double q)
    {
        n = empname;
        p = empcode;
        q = basicpay;
    }
```

`basicpay` is `double` i.e. default value is `0.0` so it will also give you zero result.

Modified code :

```
employee(String n , int p , double q) {
    this.empname = n;
    this.empcode = p;
    this.basicpay = q;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working correctly, because you multiply everything with `0`.

```
hra = 0.3*basicpay; // basicpay is 0. so 0.
da = 0.4*basicpay; // basicpay is 0. so 0.
salary = basicpay + hra + da; // 0+0+0 = 0
```

Assign a non-zero value to `basicpay`. In your constructor, you've swapped the parameters and fields. If you use `this` that mistake would be obvious, like

```
employee(String n , int p , double q)
  // n = empname;
  // p = empcode;
  // q = basicpay;
  this.empname = n;
  this.empcode = p;
  this.basicpay = q;
}
```

Also, the class name (by convention) should start with a capital letter; `Employee`.

Comment: There are too many issues with this code. Mentioning it here might be an essay it itself! :-)